# How get total distance and time from waypoints

Tags: java, android

I try to build an app that shows me a route with waypoints and display me in textview Distance and travel time.

my problem is the follow, below I have a code fragment, for calculate `total distance` and `totalSeconds`, before my app, only show me time and distance between two points, now with this code, it calculates distance and time from waypoints

This is the code fragment  for I get totalDistance and totalSeconds from all waypoints

[JSON File](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=6.3415247,-75.5577208&destination=6.3498971,-75.5567523&waypoints=optimize:true%7C6.3453442,-75.5516705%7C6.3483309,-75.5495995%7C6.3456380,-75.5491314%7C6.3455911,-75.5470564%7C6.3371096,-75.5501655%7C6.3415247,-75.5577208&key=AIzaSyDLCO4H7Bsw3OgcjYHEOnl8j5WkWLjABow)

```
public class DirectionFinder {
    private static final String DIRECTION_URL_API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyDLCO4H7Bsw3OgcjYHEOnl8j5WkWLjABow";
    private DirectionFinderListener listener;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    private String waypoints;


    public DirectionFinder(DirectionFinderListener listener, String origin, String destination, String waypoints) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.waypoints = waypoints;

    }

    public void execute() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        listener.onDirectionFinderStart();
        new DownloadRawData().execute(createUrl());
    }

    private String createUrl() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String urlOrigin = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "utf-8");
        String urlDestination = URLEncoder.encode(destination, "utf-8");
        String urlWaypoints = URLEncoder.encode(waypoints, "utf-8");


        return DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + urlOrigin + "&destination=" + urlDestination + "&waypoints=optimize:true" + urlWaypoints + "&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    }

    private class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
            try {
                parseJSon(res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


   private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
       long totalDistance = 0;
       int totalSeconds = 0;

       JSONObject jsonDistance = null;
       JSONObject jsonDuration = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");




            for (int j = 0; j < jsonLegs.length(); j++) {

                jsonDistance = ((JSONObject) jsonLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                totalDistance = totalDistance + Long.parseLong(jsonDistance.getString("value"));

                /** Getting duration from the json data */
                jsonDuration = ((JSONObject) jsonLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds + Integer.parseInt(jsonDuration.getString("value"));




            }
            route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));



            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }

       double dist = totalDistance / 1000.0;
       Log.d("distance", "Calculated distance:" + dist);

       int days = totalSeconds / 86400;
       int hours = (totalSeconds - days * 86400) / 3600;
       int minutes = (totalSeconds - days * 86400 - hours * 3600) / 60;
       int seconds = totalSeconds - days * 86400 - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
       Log.d("duration", days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " mins" + seconds + " seconds");


       listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }
```

The problem is, I need to get the totalDistance and totalSeconds from before fragment, how I do to get this data, I don't know how I do, below is my before code to get data

```
route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));

    route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
```

Comment: `from before fragment, ` ??????

Comment: Hi, i update my code

Comment: @greenapps code fragment, not Fragment class

Comment: Where/What are the waypoints?

Comment: Hi, i update again all activity and i put JSON File link

Comment: You can add more and more code... but please tell "where/what are the waypoints?".

Comment: Honestly, I don't get what the problem is, you go through toe waypoints and total them. What is not working?

Comment: Im sorry my bad english, i noob in this, the waypoints i get from  `JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");`, and i try of sum all, in the part `totalDistance = totalDistance + Long.parseLong(jsonDistance.getString("value"))`  and i need get this result in `route.distance` to pass like string for show in textview

Comment: how I do to get this data totalDistance here, this part i don't know how i do

`route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));`

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking. If you can calculate the distance between two waypoints then why cannot you add the distances up if you have a route consisting of more waypoints?